# Strict Fluid Layout | jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, styles, media, fluid-layout, fixed-width

> [View jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BFdC/)
>   or 
>   [View JS Bin](http://jsfiddle.net/3BFdC/)

I had this idea today that could combine both Fluid and Fixed width layouts and also make responsive layouts faster to build. It would also make the use of percentages in layouts work better.

To do this I'm using a similar idea to the [Frameless Grid system](http://framelessgrid.com/).

> "Adapt column by column, not pixel by pixel."

Rather than using columns, I'm adjusting the size `1 unit` at a time. The [example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BFdC/) adjusts `10px` at a time, the example shows how this could be beneficial in using percentages. It does this by using `@media` styles with `max-width` and `min-width`.

The problem I have run into is that you quickly have a lot of `@media` styles, and you would have to manually enter every single one. So I figured it could just use a fairly simple jQuery plugin. However, I have a limited knowledge of jQuery so I have only a vague idea of how this would be done which I have mapped out in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BFdC/).

> [View jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BFdC/)
>   or 
>   [View JS Bin](http://jsfiddle.net/3BFdC/)

Here is some of the CSS `@media` styles:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 249px) {.test.two {width: 240px}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 259px) and (min-width: 250px) {.test.two {width: 250px}}
...
@media only screen and (max-width: 1259px) and (min-width: 1250px) {.test.two {width: 1250px}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1260px) {.test.two {width: 1260px}}
```

And the mapped out jQuery Fiddle

```
$('.test.two').strictfluid(10px 240px 1260px); // Apply function

var resizeEvery = 'first (10px)';
var minWidth = 'second (240px)';
var maxWidth = 'third (1260px)';

var calculate = minWidth;

// First @media :
"@media only screen and (max-width: " + (min-width + (resizeEvery - 1)) + " ) {" + min-width +"}}"

    calculate = calculate + resizeEvery;

// Middle @media's (Repeat While {calculate < maxWidth})
"@media only screen and (max-width: " + (calculate + (resizeEvery - 1)) + " ) and (min-width: " + (calculate) + " ) {" + (calculate) +"}}"

    calculate = calculate + resizeEvery;

// Last @media : 
"@media only screen and (min-width: " + (max-width) + " ) {" + max-width +"}}"
```

> [View jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BFdC/)
>   or 
>   [View JS Bin](http://jsfiddle.net/3BFdC/)